# Write a shell script with find, cat and if

Tags: shell, if-statement, grep, cat

I'm doing a scipt to search a log file with an age and compare who has a string of text within the log, if it is correct to proceed to make a function, but not effected. I appreciate any advice or help

```
#!/bin/bash
file= find /AUX/backup/log/ -iname "*.log" -daystart -type f -mtime 1
if cat $file | grep -qw “INF - Status = completed."  
then
  echo "there is OK" 
else
  echo "there is KO" 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
file=`find /AUX/backup/log/ -iname "*.log" -daystart -type f -mtime 1`
if grep -qw “INF - Status = completed."  < $file
then
  echo "there is OK" 
else
  echo "there is KO" 
fi
```

Comment: Please add the explanation too, it is difficult to spot the added \` chars... (even with syntax highlight...)